# development path is confusing/not confusing with developmental path?

Tags: word-choice, difference, nouns, culture, confusable

The different development ***paths/ways/trends*** of indigenous culture in the drainage basins of the Red River, Ma River, Ca River and others converged and formed the Dong Son culture.

I feel like path is more suitable but it might be confusing with another term which is "developmental path" in psychology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that context *paths* seems most natural. It would also be possible to use *trends*. In other contexts *paths* and *trends* are not interchangeable but here either would do. I would not use *ways* here although *pathways* would be just as good as the other two. I do not think there is any realistic chance of any of them being confused with the term from psychology which you quote.